# Angular 2 , Nodejs, and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, angular

So I want to display some data on front-end from the database.

My app.js file has included:

```
app.use('/database', databaseRoutes);
```

my database.js file is the next.

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const connectionString = "postgres://dbuser:Storerage@localhost/mainstorage"

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: connectionString,
})
client.connect()

client.query('SELECT * FROM files limit 10', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  client.on("row", function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});

});
module.exports = client;
```

How can I display this postgresql query result in document.component.html.

Can somebody link me any kind of help, or write an introduction ?

I think I need create a document.service file but I don't know how to handle that. I have read about JSON.stringify, but didn't find any cool tutorial.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have trouble understanding *the concept of an API*. 
First of all you should retrieve the query results via `res.send(results)` (or res.end, whichever suits you). That will retrieve the data in a JSON format which you can easily parse using either modules like *lodash* or just simply by accessing them like any object (using either `object.attr` or `object['attr']`). You should create endpoints to which you'll send requests from your Angular front-end and those endpoints will retrieve results in JSON or whichever format. I can't go through all the steps here, but you should check out some tutorials on REST APIs for starters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Node.js server, like **Express**, or just the internal server of NodeJS is OK. I suggest Express. Then you put your code in a route's callback function, after you've fetched data form the database, use `res.send()` or `res.json()` to send result to the client. Why don't you just have a look of Express at [expressjs.com](http://expressjs.com), it's very simple. Or I should suggest you using some frameworks on a higher level to organize your code. I wrote a framework, [Cool-Node](http://cool-node.hyurl.com:3000), it base on Express and Socket.io and some other strong modules, Also, I published an ORM module, [Modelar](http://modelar.hyurl.com:3000), its easier to handle data with an ORM tool. Cool-Node uses Modelar as well, it currently supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite, with a powerful Query Constructor, it provides an API that gives you the ability to handle data in an object-oriented way.

Comment: Just a tip, set up port forwarding for your framework's website

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake, 3000, the port 80 is used by Apache, I was in PHP groups before joining nodejs.

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought :D